# Attention Something went wrong. Magento ver. 2.1.0

Tags: magento-2.1

I did a fresh intall of Magento ver. 2.1.0. The only thing I changed was that I installed the Porto theme and configured different stores.

Now every time I login and go to something like SALES - ORDERS - I get the following Error:

Attention
Something went wrong.

All in all - everywhere I go is very slow and I see the progress wheel turning a lot...

I also have another version of Magento running on the same server (different domain) - it is version 1.9.1 and it runs very smooth!

The account specs are:

**

```
Apache Version 2.4.25 
PHP Version 5.6.30 
MySQL Version 5.6.35
```

**

I also get this message when I log in to the 2.1.0 version:

Incoming Message

```
Community Editions 2.1.4 and 2.0.12 Resolve Zend Framework Security Issue & Enhance Product Quality – 2/7/2017
Read Details
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend upgrade you Magento to 2.1.5 (last stable version) and update your PHP to 7.0.16, will  runs smooth too.